# Getting value of parameter from another function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my JavaScript function that gets the value of "id" from querystring.

```
function getQueryStringValue() {
            var name = "id";
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
```

This is a jquery function that I am using to record video:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#webcam").scriptcam({
                fileReady: fileReady,
                cornerRadius: 20,
                cornerColor: 'e3e5e2',
                onError: onError,
                promptWillShow: promptWillShow,
                showMicrophoneErrors: false,
                onWebcamReady: onWebcamReady,
                setVolume: setVolume,
                timeLeft: timeLeft,
                fileName: 'demofilename',//This needs to be taken from "getQueryStringValue()"
                connected: showRecord
            });
            setVolume(0);
            $("#slider").slider({ animate: true, min: 0, max: 100, value: 50, orientation: 'vertical', disabled: true });
            $("#slider").bind("slidechange", function (event, ui) {
                $.scriptcam.changeVolume($("#slider").slider("option", "value"));
            });
        });
```

I want to get the name of file from the function "getQueryStringValue". Currently it is hard coded like :

```
fileName: 'demofilename'
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
fileName: getQueryStringValue(),
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Since other parameters are set by calling functions without paranthesis, I also tried fileName: getQueryStringValue. But your solution worked.

Comment: If there are no parenthesis, the function isn't actually being called yet. It is just being defined for use at a later time. In this case you needed to actually invoke the function, thus the parenthesis.